# Swift: Animation effect when transition between one view to another view

Tags: swift, ios8, uiimageview, uiviewanimation, uiviewanimationtransition

I am doing wow slider animation effect in my app by using swift. I added 3 images. It is sliding one by one. But I need animation like this. I don't know how to do when transition from one image to another. Kindly guide me. Animation effect is below. Not only this animation effect, but also any animation effect.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Not exactly same , but similar animation effects can be achieved using UIViewAnimations. For example try this:

```
  [UIView transitionWithView:textFieldimageView
                      duration:0.5f
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                    animations:^{
                        imageView.oldImage = newImage;
                    } completion:NULL];
```

Try this syntax for swift:

**Swift 2**

```
UIView.transitionWithView(self.view, duration: 0.5, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionCrossDissolve, animations: {
    }, completion: { (fininshed: Bool) -> () in
    })
```

**Swift 3, 4, 5**

```
UIView.transition(with: self.view, duration: 0.5, options: UIView.AnimationOptions.transitionCrossDissolve, animations: {
}, completion: { (fininshed: Bool) -> () in
})
```

Comment: Hi Abbas, I have tried in Swift. Can u help me in swift?

Comment: i have edited my answer now and added the swift code example as well, please do not forget to accept the answer if it works for you :)

Comment: Mistake is in my side. I have used scrollview to display the images, by just incrementing its offset value. So, How to add animation effect to that???

Comment: i need further elaboration on what you want your scrollview to do? and how you intend to animate it ?

Comment: scrollview->view->5 images->. Paging added. scroll one by one. image ll display like slider. How can I give animation effect? Hope u understand?

Comment: Ok, i got it now, actually the scroll view should not be in place, intead you can place the imageview on UIView and add swipe gesture to show the transition....When using a scroll you can still show the image animation ...but i am not sure how it will work ... coz from the above given image example it seems you want to show overlapping transitions between images